# If the function continuous at $x = a$ then the function is bounded around a, true or false and why?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, limits-without-lhopital

If the function continuous at $x = a$ then the function is bounded around a, true or false and why?

I think this is true because we study the continuity at $x = a$ using limit of $f(x)$ at x=a, am I right? and is my justification enough?

Comment: What does "bounded around $a$ mean" exactly?  "I think this is true because we study the continuity at x=a using limit of f(x) at x=a"  And how does that make it bounded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<1$ for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. Then $\sup_{x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)}|f(x)|\leq |f(a)|+1$.

Comment: so it is true and this is the justification?

Comment: But how you get the last inequality in line 2?

Comment: $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(a)+f(a)|\leq|f(x)-f(a)|+|f(a)|<1+|f(a)|$.